# How to copy all rows with a specific column in Excel?

Tags: excel

For example, there is such a structure:

```
---------------------------------------------
| Column_1 | Column_2 | Column_3 | Column_4 |
---------------------------------------------
| A        | B        | C        | D        |
| E        | F        | G        | H        |
| I        | J        | K        | D        |
---------------------------------------------
```

How can I copy all the lines where the text “D” is in Column_4 and paste it into another sheet?

Comment: Filter > Copy > Paste :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select Column name `Column_4`
2. Go to Home Tab - Editing - Expand Sort & Filter - Select Filter
3. Press arrow appears in Column name `Column_4` and select `D`
4. Select the filtered data
5. Right Click copy